# ASP.NET MVC Code First creating duplicate record

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ef-code-first

I am building an application using MVC and Entity Framework Code First.

I use am using an initializer to populate the database when it gets recreated through any changes to the model.

I am having problems with EF Code First creating duplicate records. The easiest way to explain would be to show you my code.

```
    //
    // POST: /Incident/CreateIncident
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateIncident(IncidentViewModel model)
    {
        Incident incidentToAdd = new Incident();

        // Record incident details
        incidentToAdd.Caller = repository.GetDomainUser(model.selectedCaller);
        incidentToAdd.CallerType = model.Incident.CallerType;
        incidentToAdd.Service = repository.GetService(model.selectedService);
        incidentToAdd.Category = repository.GetCategory(model.selectedCategory);
        incidentToAdd.AllocatedTo = repository.GetHelpDeskMember(model.selectedAllocatedTo);

        [Rest of code omitted to save space]

        // TODO: Send Email to Caller and AllocatedTo

        // Store incident in database
        db.Incidents.Add(incidentToAdd);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

I am getting the existing Service, Category and AllocatedTo from a repository, but when it comes to save the record, instead of linking to the existing Service, Category, etc. It creates a new record which is a duplicate of the existing.

I didn't really explain that very well. But if you can offer any help it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like the Service and Category records on the incident are not actually attached to the DbContext.  Either the DbContext used in the repository is not the same as one in the controller, or the repository is returning detatched entities.  What exactly does repositry.GetService look like - is it using the same DbContext that your controller is?

Comment: @Leniency, Yes Repository and Controller are using exactly the same context. The GetService() method looks like this: `public Service GetService(int id)
        {
            return db.Services.SingleOrDefault(s => s.ServiceID == id);
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. I'm not sure if it's the correct way to do it, but I'm getting the result I wanted.

Now instead of simply adding the entity returned from the database to incidentToAdd, I'm now using EntityState to specify the entity as unchanged.

```
Service service = repository.GetService(model.selectedService);
incidentToAdd.Service = service;
db.Entry(service).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

Category category = repository.GetCategory(model.selectedCategory);
incidentToAdd.Category = category;
db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

HelpDeskMember allocatedTo = repository.GetHelpDeskMember(model.selectedAllocatedTo);
incidentToAdd.AllocatedTo = allocatedTo;
db.Entry(allocatedTo).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

I found the information here at this link: [Using DbContext in EF 4.1 Part 4: Add/Attach and Entity States](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx/)